# Installing Ubuntu 10.04 on Windows 2008 R2 Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, ubuntu-10.04

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 10.04 on Hyper-V on windows server 2008 R2 but it continually fails.  I have tried using a legacy network adapter and I keep getting a red screen saying installation step failed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help

http://blogs.technet.com/b/enterprise_admin/archive/2010/03/09/linux-and-hyper-v-the-easy-way-brown-and-serve.aspx